# Java: calcular porcentaje de descuento

Tags: java, condiciones

el Problema me pide que dada "n" cantidad de productos solicitar una conversion de dolares a pesos, el dolar tiene un valor de $19.10, y me dice que si la compra es de $300 no se aplica ningun descuento,si la compra va de $300 a $1000 se aplica 40% de descuento, y si la compra es mayor a $1000 se aplica el 60% de descuento

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner leer=new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Introduzca la cantidad de dinero en dolares");
    int dolar=leer.nextInt();
    double a,b;
    a=19.10;
    b=dolar*a;
    double N = 0,monto =;

    if(N<=300){
        monto=N;
        System.out.println(monto);
    } 
    else if(N>=300 && N>=1000){
        monto= N-(N*0.4);
        System.out.println(monto);
    }
    else if(N>1000){
        monto= N-(N*0.6);
        System.out.println(monto);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(N);
    }




}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: y cual seria el problema que estas teniendo? tenes que ser mas claro con las preguntas. Que resultados esperas y cual estas recibiendo. si necesitas agregar informacion, usa el boton [edit]

Comment: lo que se ve a simple vista, es que N siempre vale 0, porque nunca le estas asignando ningun valor.

Answer (score 1):

Como bien ha dicho [gbianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi) en uno de los comentarios, la variable `N` está inicializada a 0 y no se le pasa ningún valor, por tanto tu lógica con los `if` nunca saldrá el resultado que esperas.

La opción mas sencilla sería sustituir la variable N por b y con eso ya aplicaría la lógica.

```
double a, N, monto; //Eliminamos la variable b y creamos la variable N en su lugar
a=19.10;
N=dolar*a;
if(N<=300){
.
.
//resto de la lógica
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda es que estoy empezando en esto y aun no lo domino, pero pues en verdad muchas gracias amigo

Comment: @FelipeReyesSalazar de nada, también te recomiendo visitar [ask] para que las próximas veces que realices consultas las desarrolles de la forma correcta, un saludo!