# java determinar porcentaje de descuento

Tags: java, condiciones

Debo generar un programa que determine la cantidad a pagar en una tienda, la cual debido a su aniversario, ofrece descuentos dependiendo el monto de compra. Se deberá mostrar el total de la compra, el descuento y la cantidad que pagará la persona con el descuento aplicado.

Descuentos:

```
> $10,000 20% de descuento
> $5,000  10% de descuento
< $5,000   0% de descuento
```

Quiero aclarar que nunca tome clases de Java y la escuela me pide este curso de 3 semanas para pasar la materia. Hice el siguiente código, pero solo me muestra la cantidad de venta y la cantidad final que el cliente debe pagar con el descuento aplicado. No puedo hacer que muestre el resultado como el profesor me pide, que es:

```
Total de la compra:
Descuento aplicado:
Total a Pagar:
```

A continuación el código que hice, mil gracias....

```
package descuento.de.compra;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class DescuentoDeCompra {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    double compra;

        System.out.println("Ingrese el monto de la compra:");
        compra = teclado.nextDouble(); 
   
    int total = (int) compra;
        total=teclado.nextDuble();
        
        if (compra > 10000 ){
            compra = compra - (compra*0.2);
        }
        else if (compra > 5000){
            compra = compra - (compra*0.1);
        }
        else if (compra < 5000){
            compra = compra - (compra*0.0);
        }
        System.out.println("El monto a pagar despues de haber aplicado descuento es:"+compra);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Bienvenida al sitio Johaly, te invitamos a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas el funcionamiento básico del sitio, saludos!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Java: calcular porcentaje de descuento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/138362/java-calcular-porcentaje-de-descuento)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente te comento que en este punto declaras `total` como entero pero tratas de almacenar en ella un valor double,  lo cual no tiene mucho sentido.

```
    int total = (int) compra;
    total=teclado.nextDouble();
```

Puedes definir tu variable total como `double` para que puedas almacenar valores con punto decimal, de otra forma definela como `int`, tu decides.

Tu código es casi correcto, te sugiero primeramente inicializar las variables que usaras para realizar operaciones y posteriormente implementar la lógica. Si vas a imprimir varios valores usa variables para almacenar estos valores, aquí faltaría una variable para almacenar el `descuento` :

```
package descuento.de.compra;

  import java.text.DecimalFormat;
  import java.text.NumberFormat;
  import java.util.Scanner;

public class DescuentoDeCompra {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Inicializa Scanner
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    //inicializa variable compra.
    double compra;
    //inicializa variable total.
    double total = 0;        
    //Inicializa variable para almacenar descuento.        
    double descuento = 0;

    System.out.println("Ingrese el monto de la compra:");
    //Obtiene mediante teclado el valor de la compra
    compra = teclado.nextDouble();


    if (compra > 10000) {
        descuento = 0.2;
        total = compra - (compra * descuento);
    } else if (compra > 5000) {
        descuento = 0.1;
        total = compra - (compra * descuento);
    } else if (compra < 5000) {
        descuento = 0.0;
        total = compra - (compra * descuento);
    }

    System.out.println("Total de la compra: " + compra);
    System.out.println("Descuento aplicado: " + descuento);
    System.out.println("Total a Pagar: " + total);
}
}
```

Incluso puedes hacer uso de formateadores para mostrar tus resultados de una forma más entendible para el usuario:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Inicializa Scanner
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    //inicializa variable compra.
    double compra;
    //inicializa variable total.
    double total = 0;        
    //Inicializa variable para almacenar descuento.        
    double descuento = 0;

    System.out.println("Ingrese el monto de la compra:");
    //Obtiene mediante teclado el valor de la compra
    compra = teclado.nextDouble();


    if (compra > 10000) {
        descuento = 0.2;
        total = compra - (compra * descuento);
    } else if (compra > 5000) {
        descuento = 0.1;
        total = compra - (compra * descuento);
    } else if (compra < 5000) {
        descuento = 0.0;
        total = compra - (compra * descuento);
    }

    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
    System.out.println("Total de la compra: $" + formatter.format(compra));
    NumberFormat defaultFormat = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
    defaultFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
    System.out.println("Descuento aplicado: " + defaultFormat.format(descuento));
    System.out.println("Total a Pagar: $" + formatter.format(total));

 }
```

Ejemplo:

```
Ingrese el monto de la compra:
14000

Total de la compra: $14,000
Descuento aplicado: 20%
Total a Pagar: $11,200
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema del código que has puesto es que has reutilizado la variable compra para el valor de la compra y para el total a pagar, por lo que cuando calculas el total a pagar machacas el valor de la compra y pierdes ese dato para mostrarlo después.

Se puede hacer de varias maneras, te dejo aquí una manera:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese el monto de la compra: ");
    double compra = teclado.nextDouble(); 
    double descuento;
    if (compra > 10000) {
       descuento = 0.2;
    } else if (compra > 5000) {
       descuento = 0.1;
    } else {
       descuento = 0;
    }
    double total = compra - (compra * descuento);
    System.out.println("Total de la compra: " + compra);
    System.out.println("Descuento aplicado: " + descuento);
    System.out.println("Total a pagar: " + total);
}
```

En este ejemplo uso tres variables, uno por cada valor a mostrar, en compra está lo que se recibe por la entrada estándar, descuento se calcula en función del valor de compra, y el total se aplica en función del valor de compra y del descuento. Después se muestran los tres datos por la salida estándar.